# werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.flask web app

Tags: python, html, css, flask, python-requests

How to solve this error? I am new to flask

> - Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2020 11:19:45] "GET /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
> KeyError: 'namequery'

```
<div class="container">
<form action="/predict" , method="POST">
    <p>
        <!--{{form.submit}} login button  from wtf -->
        <input type='text', name="namequery">
        <input type="submit" , value="Predict" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="submit" , value="Reset" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </p>
    <h2>Prediction</h2>
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
```

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    namequery=''
    if request.method=='POST':
        namequery= request.form['`namequery`']
        data=[namequery]
    else:
        namequery= request.form['namequery']
    render_template("/predict",name=namequery)
```

Comment: Html Content correction:

Comment: <div class="container">
    <form action="/predict" , method="POST">
        <p>
            <!--{{form.submit}} login button  from wtf -->
            <input type='text', name="namequery">
            <input type="submit" , value="Predict" class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="submit" , value="Reset" class="btn btn-secondary">
        </p>
        <h2>Prediction</h2>
        <p>{{ name }}</p>
    </form>
</div>

Comment: _“correction”_ — Please [edit] your question to include any corrections.

Comment: Why are there commas between HTML attributes?

Comment: @SachinDahivadkar I've edited your code. Please check if it represents what your actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so when your `request.method='POST'`, you're accessing the variable `namequery` from the `form` that was posted. But your code also expects the variable `request.form` to be present, when the `request.method='GET'`.

That doesn't make any sense as no form is actually posted when the method is `GET`.

Please edit your code, if you want to convey something else.